# Server cannnot connect with My SQL database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, model-view-controller

I'm trying to make a web mvc using spring, hibernate and maven. I need to transfer data from .jsp forms to sql database. For example: from signup.jsp to the respective table in My Sql database. But hibernate doesn't automatically create the required tables and database and gives the following errors.

```
SEVERE: End event threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addServlet
at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethod1(IntrospectionUtils.java:849)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetNextRule.end(SetNextRule.java:201)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1063)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1561)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.parseWebXml(ContextConfig.java:1825)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1263)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5380)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

// entity

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.type.PrimitiveByteArrayBlobType;

@Entity
@Table(name="Client")
public class Client {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    private String email;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="order")
    private List<Books> inCart;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

java

```
//Implementation
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.ob.myapp.model.Books;
import com.ob.myapp.model.Client;

@Repository
public class ClientDaoImpl implements ClientDao{
    @Resource
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        @Override
    @Transactional
    public boolean addNewClient(Client client) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.save(client);
        return true;
    }

}
```

java

```
//Controller class

package com.ob.myapp.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.ob.myapp.dao.ClientDao;
import com.ob.myapp.dao.ClientDaoImpl;
import com.ob.myapp.model.Client;

@Controller
public class SignupController {
    @Autowired
    private ClientDao cdao;
    @RequestMapping(value="/signup", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String getSignup(){
            return "signup";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/signup", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String Signup(@ModelAttribute Client client){
        cdao.addNewClient(client);
        return "login";
    }
}
```

xml

```
 //servlet-context
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Package location which contain all the spring annotations like @Autowire, 
        @Repository, @Resource -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ob.myapp" />

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>




    <!-- DataSource for JDBC connection -->

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>




    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <!-- Package where all the Entity(model) exits. -->
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.ob.myapp.model</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction Manager to make Transaction Support -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

<bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20000000" />
    </bean>




</beans>
```

//web.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">


    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Error clearly says "root-context.xml" not found do you have that file under "/WEB-INF/spring" as you mentioned in the context xml file?

Comment: Add your web.xml code.

Comment: seriously learn to read `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]`

Comment: I removed <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
 </context-param> from servlet context but there still errors(I edited the question). Sorry I'm really new to this.